# Connections iWidget and xPages login

Tags: xpages, ibm-connections

I am using an xPage as an iWidget in IBM Connections 3.0.1. I have extended the ajax proxy to point to the nsf. During testing everything was working correctly but I realized it was only working when I was already authenticated with the application (I do use SPENEGO to auth). When I load connections in a fresh browser session I get the BMWIW0001E:Unable to load iWidget error. But if I load the app then reload connections all is well.

Is there a way to pass through the user's credentials or otherwise prompt for a login?

Is there a way to hide the "BMWIW0001E:Unable to load iWidget " error and display a custom error page?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is generated afaik by connections, so you might  be better of asking on Server fault or the IBM Connections forum.

For authentication in a mixed environment you have to sort out the trust relationship between the servers. Pick your poison: LTPA, oAuth, not sure about spinego.

As a short term remedy you could use a landing xpage in your widget flagged for anonymous access (allow public access and in the ACL: anonymous with no access but read public access.

In that page you check @UserName  and redirect to a mini login or the real widget page.  Redirect can be also by loading a dynamic control

Comment: I tagged the post with both connections and xpages, seemed the prudent thing to do with the cross pollination. The landing page idea is a great one, I think i am going to try that in the short term. Thanks!

Comment: No issue with the tagging :-). The connections side looks like an admin issue and the admins hang out at serverfault next door :-)